# How is sharepoint list data structured?

Tags: database, database-design, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I am curious about how sharepoint stores its list data. 
From what I know, a list can have dynamic column numbers and you can even change the data type of a column after a list is created. How does sharepoint do this ?

I am asking because I have to create a structure to store some data. But the number of columns of these data is very likely to be changed in the future. I think I can draw something from sharepoint's list database design.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the schema for the Sharepoint Lists table:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585174%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Also:

- [Sharepoint database tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587562%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
- [Microsoft SharePoint Products and Technologies Protocol Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25255)

Happy reading :)